# Python script run via Windows Task scheduler

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, scheduled-tasks, pyautogui

I have the following automation script which works fine with VS Code and Python IDLE. It opens  the Application as desired upon double click.

I ran the same script via Windows task scheduler. The task scheduler report success. However my application gui does not open

---

Action  : Program - full path to the python.exe executable
Start in - the location of .py file
Optional Arguments - the .py file

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

pyautogui.screenshot('C:/users/GeoV/downloads/t1.png')
de = pyautogui.size()
print(de.width)
ft = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:/users/GeoV/downloads/Capture1.png')

print(ft)

pyautogui.doubleClick('C:/users/GeoV/downloads/Capture1.png')

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: In order to see any output your code produces (including error message), it will have to be running in a `cmd` shell, so you need to make that the program to start and pass it the path to the Python interpreter and another to the script you want it to execute.

Comment: so i tried cmd (in program/script) C:\Users\GeoV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe piauto1.py  (in Add arguments optional) and location of .py file in start in , I am not seeing error on task - ompleted successfully when it was run, but no desired outcome

Comment: That's not what I meant, which was — run `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` with something like the following arguments: `/k C:\Python3\python.exe C:\path\to\script\task.py`.